# How to parse json array into string for use as parameters later in jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

Sample input as below:

> `[{"program":"C:/temp/abc.exe","actions":"9","file_name":"abc1","new_file_name":"newabc1","version":"2.0.0.0","product_name":"abc","description":"abc","eventdate":"20160601120000"},{"program":"C:/temp/abc.exe","actions":"9","file_name":"abc2","new_file_name":"newabc2","version":"2.0.0.0","product_name":"abc","description":"abc","eventdate":"20160601120000"}]`

I need to parse this json array into string for use in the following http request as parameters. I new to jmeter and tried to follow the example in http://theworkaholic.blogspot.my/2012/05/json-in-jmeter.html but i can't seem to get the value of **jsonResponse** at last.

[UPDATE]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDS9P.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, however here are some clues:

1. If you need to store the whole response into a JMeter Variable for later re-use - go for [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured as follows:

   - Reference Name: anythingMeaningful, i.e. `jsonResponse`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. If you need 2 separate JSON Objects from the array - [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) is available since JMeter 3.0

   - `$.[0]` - for 1st JSON Array item
   - `$.[1]` - for 2nd JSON Array item

     [image: JSON Path PostProcessor Demo]
3. If you need anything else - use the same JSON Path PostProcessor. I would recommend getting familiarized with the following material:

   - [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
   - [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Still no luck - update your question with **exact** details on how you need to re-use that JSON data in next request(s)

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. I have attached screenshot to better explained by question.

Comment: Check out *jmeter.log* file - it normally contains some information regarding Beanshell error. Also try  your code in [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) and  in catch block use something like `log.error("Error", ex)` - you will be able to see the stacktrace in *jmeter.log* file. Also JMeter comes with net.minidev.json, not with org.json - make sure you have the relevant jar in classpath. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for details